# Save names as a list from a function running numerous univariate regression models

Tags: r, model, regression, logistic-regression, feature-selection

I am building a logistic regression model with a data set containing about 40 variables. The first step I use when building these types of models is I run each variable univariately with the DV (Hosmer, Lemeshow, & Sturdivant, 2013). I have built a function that does this for me and returns the p-value of each.

```
Fit Univariate logistic regression model for each covariate
uni.log2 <- function(x) {
  log.mod2 <- glm(Renewf ~ x, data = dt.train2, family = binomial())
  return(coef(summary(log.mod2))[,4]) #get p-values only
}
```

I then apply this function to each of the selected columns in my dt

```
#apply function to selected IV's 
apply(X = dt.train2[c(3:16)], MARGIN = 2, FUN = uni.log2)
```

The next step I would like to do is screen these variables for a p-values with a threshold of p < 0.25 and return a list of the names of the variables which were univariately significant at p < 0.25.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

I am able to set a threshold and copy a list of names from a multivariate model using this code:

```
threshold <- 0.001
signif_form <- as.formula(paste("Renewf ~ 
",paste(names(which((summary(log.mod2)$coefficients[2: 
(nrow(summary(log.mod2)$coefficients)), 4] < threshold) == TRUE)), collapse 
= "+")))
```

But, again, I do not know how to paste the names from the series of univariate regression models. If someone knows how to do this I would greatly appreciate some help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: May I politely suggest that you might try a different approach? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to use this approach after looking over the link provided by @BenBolker (and perhaps other resources on the perils of [stepwise regression](https://www.lexjansen.com/pnwsug/2008/DavidCassell-StoppingStepwise.pdf) and [statistical significance](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/the-statistical-crisis-in-science))...

The following code will return a vector of p-values for the independent variable in each regression. I've used the built-in `mtcars` data frame for illustration.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

pvals = sapply(names(mtcars)[names(mtcars) != "vs"], function(x) {
  glm(paste("vs ~ ", x), data=mtcars, family=binomial) %>% 
    tidy %>% 
    filter(term==x) %>% pull(p.value)
})

pvals
```

> ```
>         mpg         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec          am 
> 0.006590045 0.001917098 0.002453817 0.012340143 0.021777872 0.008672977 0.008813419 0.343628917 
>        gear        carb 
> 0.250981095 0.004157666
> ```

The code above uses the pipe operator (`%>%`) to chain functions together. After creating the model with `glm`, `tidy` returns the coefficients and p-values as a data frame:

```
glm(vs ~ mpg, data=mtcars, family=binomial) %>% 
    tidy
```

> ```
>          term   estimate std.error statistic     p.value
> 1 (Intercept) -8.8330726  3.162274 -2.793266 0.005217877
> 2         mpg  0.4304135  0.158422  2.716880 0.006590045
> ```

Then the `filter` and `pull` functions select the p-value for the particular variable under consideration:

```
glm(vs ~ mpg, data=mtcars, family=binomial) %>% 
  tidy %>% filter(term=="mpg") %>% pull(p.value)
```

> ```
> [1] 0.006590045
> ```

Wrapping the whole thing in `sapply` returns a named vector of p-values, where the names are the independent variables in each univariate regression.

To return only elements below a p-value threshold:

```
pvals[pvals < 0.25]
```

> ```
>         mpg         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec        carb 
> 0.006590045 0.001917098 0.002453817 0.012340143 0.021777872 0.008672977 0.008813419 0.004157666
> ```

If you just want the names of the variables that meet the threshold criterion:

```
names(pvals[pvals < 0.25])
```

To directly return just the elements below the p-value threshold:

```
pvals = sapply(names(mtcars)[names(mtcars) != "vs"], function(x) {
  glm(paste("vs ~ ", x), data=mtcars, family=binomial) %>% 
    tidy %>% 
    filter(term==x) %>% pull(p.value)
}) %>% .[. < 0.25]
```

Finally, packaging this as a function to return the names of the desired variables:

```
select_vars = function(DV, data, threshold) {
  sapply(names(data)[names(data) != DV], function(x) {
    glm(paste(DV, " ~ ", x), data=data, family=binomial) %>% 
      tidy %>% 
      filter(term==x) %>% pull(p.value)
  }) %>% .[. < threshold] %>% names
}

select_vars("vs", mtcars, 0.25)
```

> ```
> [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "carb"
> ```

```
select_vars("Species", iris %>% filter(Species %in% c("versicolor","virginica")), 0.001)
```

> ```
> [1] "Sepal.Length" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
> ```

Comment: thank you!! That was awesome. Exactly what I needed.